# Transform struct/array of arrays into a single array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, matlab-struct

I have a Matlab struct that contains arrays. Specifically it is allocated like this:

```
info(27).field1 = [];
info(27).field2 = [];
info(27).field3 = [];
```

It's filled via a loop

```
% here simplified for your convenience
for i = 1:27
    info(i).field1 = rand(1,4);
    info(i).field2 = rand(1,4);
    info(i).field3 = rand(1,4);
```

And when filled (with my values) looks like this:

```
[1048576;0;0;0] [1;0;0;0]   [1;0;0;0]
[1047512;0;1064;0]  [0,99;0;0,01;0] [1;0;8;0]
[1047900;0;676;0]   [0,94;0;0,07;0] [2;0;3;0]
...
```

I want this to be a single (27x12) table that I can save as a table-file with the single values of the arrays being columns (using `writetable(T,'myData.csv', ...')`
Somewhat looking like this (table headings may be neglected):

```
1.A     1.B 1.C     1.D     2.A     2.B 2.C 2.D     3.A 3.B 3.C 3.D
___     ___ ___     ___     ___     ___ ___ ___     ___ ___ ___ ___
1048576 0   0       0       1,00    0   0       0   1   0   0   0
1047512 0   1064    0       0,99    0   0,01    0   1   0   8   0
1047900 0   676     0       0,94    0   0,07    0   2   0   3   0
```

Or even better

```
1.A     1.B 1.C     1.D     2.A     2.B 2.C 2.D     3.A 3.B 3.C 3.D
___     ___ ___     ___     ___     ___ ___ ___     ___ ___ ___ ___
1048576 0   0       0       100%    0%  0%  0%      1   0   0   0
1047512 0   1064    0       99%     0%  1%  0%      1   0   8   0
1047900 0   676     0       94%     0%  7%  0%      2   0   3   0
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
T = table(info)    %obviously doesn't work

 info     
_____________

[1x27 struct]
```

And a workaround with a cell array

```
% create a cell array and try to concatenate the arrays in the array
C = struct2cell(info)
Cp = permute(C,[3 1 2]);
Cpx = horzcat(Cp(:,1),Cp(:,2),Cp(:,3));
T = table(Cpx)

T = 

                  Cpx                   
________________________________________

[4x1 double]  [4x1 double]  [4x1 double]
[4x1 double]  [4x1 double]  [4x1 double]
[4x1 double]  [4x1 double]  [4x1 double]
...
```

I thought horzcat would work, but somehow I can't wrap my head around why it doesn't. Somebody with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `horzcat` simply concatenates the three columns of `Cp` (as cell arrays). They already are the columns so the output is the same as the input.

If you want to concatenate the *contents* together, you can first convert to a matrix using `cell2mat` and then pass this directly to `array2table` to create the `table`.

```
T = array2table(cell2mat(Cp));
```

**Update**

If your original vectors are `4x1` instead, you can do the following:

```
T = array2table(squeeze(cell2mat(struct2cell(info))).')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this in several variants, but got stuck with a little detail:

Comment: @Honeybear It looks like your comment got chopped off. What was the detail?

Comment: The vectors contained in the struct were vertical (4x1), therefore `cell2mat(Cp)` vertically stacked the values (27x3 struct became a 108x3 matrix). To fix that I changed the vectors contained in the struct (e.g. `[1;0;0;0]`) to horizontal ones  (e.g. `[1 0 0 0]` with `v = v'`. Don't know how you would do that without a loop). Then it worked (27x12 table). Thanks a lot.

P.S.: sorry, accidentally send the comment with Enter trying to do a line break ;)

Comment: @Honeybear In your initial post they were 1 x 4 so that's what I assumed they were in your data. I have added additional method for if they are 4 x 1.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, works like a charm. Upvoted, but still to little rep to show the vote.

Comment: @Honeybear You shouldn't need any rep to *see* the votes.

Comment: What I meant is, when I upvote your answer, stack overflow tells me: _Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._ ;)

Comment: @Honeybear Oh interesting. I didn't realize that!